# Json webservice values are not loading in datatables. Showing error of "TypeError: c is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I am retrieving json  values from java server and loading it in the datables.While parsing it shows the error of `TypeError: c is undefined`.

Html coding:

```
<table id="employeeTable" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Id.</th>
            <th >Division</th>                                                  
            <th >Name</th>                                                                                                      
            <th >Mobile number</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JS Coding

```
$('#employeeTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "http://192.168.1.3:8080/alpharithm/employee/employeeDetails",
        "aoColumns": [ 
                    { "sName": "division", "sTitle": "Employee Id.", "sWidth": "20%", "bSortable": "true" },
                    { "sName": "employee_id", "sTitle": "Division", "sWidth": "40%", "bSortable": "true" },
                    { "sName": "last_name", "sTitle": "Name", "sWidth": "40%", "bSortable": "true" },
                    { "sName": "first_name", "sTitle": "Mobile number", "sWidth": "20%", "bSortable": "true" }
        ],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "Page length: _MENU_",
            "sSearch": "Filter:",
            "sZeroRecords": "No matching records found"
                    },

});
```

JSON Response

```
{"employee_details":[{"division":"Android","employee_id":"EFF100568","last_name":"lastname","first_name":"name"}],"status":"1"}
```

Help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error often seems to be thrown by corrupted data... Could we see what your ajax source looks like ?
(Sorry this is not an answer but I can't post comments to ask more informations...)

Edit : Your source should looks like :

```
{
    "data": [
        ["Android","EFF100568","lastname","name","1"],
        ["Android2","EFF100568","lastname","name","1"]
    ]
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I tested with this ajax response and it works. Your server side script should be corrected.